# Ubuntu desktop (gnome) running as a background process

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, desktop, gdm

I've got this instance of Ubuntu server where after booting up gdm start a session automatically and the desktop graphical interface runs offline as a background process i.e not on the standard output (screen). The system has anydesk installed and so I can access the desktop environment without a problem through it. I am looking for a way to bring back the desktop environment to show up on the screen.
I have checked the current target and it is at graphical.target

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gnome-session DISPLAY environment variable for setting the X display being used by gnome-session.
(Note that if the --display option is used this might be different from the setting of the environment variable when gnome-session is invoked.)

Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-session.1.html

hope it helps, thanks!